# What is the origin of using Q to denote a set of states in an automaton?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, notation, history

When talking about DFAs and NFAs as 5-tuples, it's common to use the letter $Q$ to denote the set of states in the automaton and to denote individual states with names like $q_0$, $q_1$, etc.

Is there a particular reason why the letter $Q$ was chosen? As in, is $Q$ the first letter of a word historically related to automata? Or was it chosen totally arbitrarily?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The symbol $q$ to denote the state of a finite automaton appears (for the first time??) in Moore's 1956 paper [Gedanken-Experiments on Sequential Machines](http://people.mokk.bme.hu/~kornai/termeszetes/moore_1956.pdf) and since the paper became very popular, I suppose that Moore's notation has been adopted since then. Apparently, Moore didn't use any special notation for the set of states, but it you adopt $q$ for a state, $Q$ seems to be an obvious choice for the set of states.

I don't think there is any special meaning for the letter $q$ (or $Q$).

[1] E.F. Moore, Gedanken experiments on sequential machines. In C. E. Shannon and J. McCarthy, editors, Automata Studies, 129–156. Princeton University Press, 1956.